# QListWidget: More icons on one row

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

For my bachelor thesis I'm programming an Role Playing Game maker. I'm making use of tilesets (left picture below). I load such an image in my project and split it in small square blocks (tiles). Now, I load these in a QListWidget, but I would like the QListWidget to show as many tiles in a row as there are in the image (for example: the image below contains 8 tiles/row, but in my program, the QListWidget only shows 6 tiles per row).

I have tried to work with layouts, but these don't seem to work. Any idea on how to let the QListWidget display a custom amount of items per row? I like to work with the QListWidget because it provides a good way of selecting the tiles and propagating to the parent widgets which tile should be drawn in another widget.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may have an easier time using a QTreeWidget or QTableWidget.

Comment: I have been blindly staring on how I could get it working with the QListWidget that I forgot to look at other types... Thank you for pointing that out! The QTableWidget seems to be perfect for the job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may have an easier time using a QTreeWidget or QTableWidget.

Answer (score 0):

well... I am not 100 % happy with the current answer from user336063

the QListWidget has a "viewMode" property,

[image]

if you set that to IconMode your list will look like:

[image]

by default it looks like:

[image]