# Can't display icons in QListWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019431/qlistwidget-more-icons-on-one-row)

The problem is that I'm unable to show even icons.
Those icons are supposed to come from single files which it takes from a temporal folder.

```
self.resourceView.setIconSize(QSize(self.tileWH,self.tileWH))
files = os.listdir(self.tmp_dir)
files.sort()
for i in files:
    icon = QIcon(i)
    item = QListWidgetItem(icon, None)
    self.resourceView.addItem(item)
```

resourceView is the QListWidget.
files are, of course, the icons.
Obviously this code is an example of what I'm doing.

And this is the result

[image]

The items are there, but the icon is not being displayed.

Comment: Could you show an image of what you want to get?

Comment: You need to check if you really load the icons. Debug your application and look at the content of variable icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns the name of the files but QIcon needs the fullpath of the file, that is why the image is not shown, the solution is to concatenate the directory the file name:

```
files = os.listdir(self.tmp_dir)
files.sort()
for file in files:
    icon = QIcon(os.path.join(self.tmp_dir, file))
    item = QListWidgetItem(icon, None)
    resourceView.addItem(item)
```

Comment: It doesn't return an error. I'm angry because I was using all the time wrongly one of their data types and it never showed an error.

Btw, this worked, thanks!

Comment: @JuanMartínez Greetings from Peru. :P